# Java custom tooltip for minimize button

Tags: java, button, jframe, tooltip, minimize

I am creating a JFrame in the following way.

```
    JFrame f=new JFrame("Title");
    f.setUndecorated(true);
    f.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
```

However, I am trying to display a custom tooltip text for the JFrame (by default it shows "Iconify"). Please help me out.

Thanks !

Comment: If you set the `setUndecorated(true)` , how will you have the minimze button?? I guess it should be false

Comment: The line
   f.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
actually adds the minimize and close buttons ... however they are not the default L&F but taken from the root pane ... that is by design

Answer (score 1):

One way add some panel to frame with tooltip you needed:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setToolTipText("Message");
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Another way if you have custom minimize button:

```
JButton button = new JButton() {
  public JToolTip createToolTip() {
    JToolTip tip = super.createToolTip();
    tip.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    tip.setForeground(Color.RED);
    return tip;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change text of minimize button in L&F, you can set `InternalFrameTitlePane.minimizeButtonText` value if `UIDefaults`.

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("InternalFrameTitlePane.minimizeButtonText", "my text");
```

It can be used as a solution if you definitely know which L&F your application will use.